# Matrix/vector proof

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, vectors

Let $C$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with real entries. For vectors $u,v\in\mathbb R^m$,
we define $u\sim v$ if there exists a vector $x\in\mathbb R^n$
such that $Cx = u−v$.
Prove that for all $u, v,w \in\mathbb R^m$:

i) $u \sim u$;

ii) if $u \sim v$ then $v \sim u$;

iii) if $u \sim v$ and $v \sim w$ then $u \sim w$.

Question from homework, but we haven't seen this in class, so I have no clue how to go about it and start.

Do I make up a matrix and prove it that way? Is that proof of this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's just focus on (i) for now. You have to prove the claim for **every** matrix $C$, so making up one particular one is not the way to go. Let's first write down the definition we need. By definition, we have

> $$ u\sim v\iff \exists x\in\mathbb R^n: Cx=u-v$$

write down the claim you need to prove:

> For all $u\in\mathbb R^m$, the claim $u\sim u$ is true.

Clearly, as all "for all" claim proofs start, you must begin by saying:

> Let $u\in\mathbb R^m$.

Now, you must prove that $u\sim u$. To do that:

1. write down what it means, by definition, that $u\sim u$.
2. using that definition, first think about what you need to do to prove the definition
3. **only once you completed steps one and two**: prove the definition.

In a comment (or as an edit to your quesiton), tell us: which of the steps above is giving you problems? We can help you further once we know where the problem is.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't really know what u∼u means by definition, as we've only used this when producing a rref of a matrix for example.

Comment: @Sarah1232 The **definition** of "$u\sim v$" is "There exists some $x$ such that $Cx=u-v$.

Comment: So then Cx = 0 for part i), but how is that a proof?

Comment: @Sarah1232 That's not a proof. Please, follow points 1, 2 and 3 I wrote down in my answer. You are clearly very confused, and in this way, you have zero chance of solving the problem. Slow down. Relax. This is mathematics. You need to do things one tiny step at a time. Never take a single step you are not 100% sure in.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, you can start with a particular matrix, however in order to prove the statement you need to make it in general finding excplicty the vector $x$.

For the first point if you pick $x=0$ then you obtain $Cx = 0 = u-u$ which implies that condition i) is true.

For the second point  you start from the condition $u\sim v$ which means that there exists $x$ such that $Cx=u-v$, if you consdier $-x$ you get what you need.

For the third point still your hypothesy gives you that there exist $x$ and $y$ such that 
$Cx=u-v$ and $Cy=v-w$, then $C(x+y) = u-v+v-w = u-w$.